# Rails error: ArgumentError in ArticlesController#create wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

i have tutorial on Rails from here:
[Rails5](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

and wanted to add a field "attachment" to the form.
articles_controller.rb is as follows:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

http_basic_authenticate_with name: "gerrit", password: "Ifb6K54WVs7U", except: [:index, :show]

def index
  @articles = Article.all
end

def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end



def new
  @article = Article.new
end

def edit
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)

  if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def update
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])

  if @article.update(article_params)
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.destroy

  redirect_to articles_path
end

private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :attachment)
  end
end
```

For this i added paperclip and turbolink5.

I rerun all configuring steps in the tutorial but I always get the error in the title:

```
  Extracted source (around line #24):

def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)

  if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
```

I do not use single params here, but article_params!?
Any help appreciated!

Comment: anybody? My question is: how can `@article = Article.new(article_params)` have wrong **number** of arguments, when there are only `article_params`

Comment: I updated paperclip to v5.1.0 and the error was gone. In a paperclip related issue validating of mime types other than image does not work: [link](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1771).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the last comment:

I updated paperclip to v5.1.0 and the error was gone.